# When I run this C++ program, sales name 1 does not print out

Tags: c++, arrays

I do not have any error but when I run the program sales name 1 not print out. I am using C++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>

using namespace std;


void getData(string names[],double sales[3][4]); void
calTotalSales(string names[],double sales[3][4]);

int main() { double sales[3][4]; string names[3];

getData(names,sales);

calTotalSales(names,sales);    return 0; }

void getData(string names[],double sales[3][4]) {

   for(int i=0;i<3;i++)    {

       cout<<"Enter in the name of the salesman "<<i+1<<": ";
       cin>>names[i];

       cout<<"Now Enter in the sales for each quarter for "<<names[i]<<endl;
       for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
       {
           cout<<"Enter in the data for the quarter "<<j+1<<": ";
           cin>>sales[i][j];
       }
       cout<<endl;    } }


void calTotalSales(string names[],double sales[3][4]) {

   double max;    string name;    int i;



   cout << setprecision(2) << fixed;

       for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
       {

       max = sales[0][j];
       for(i = 0; i < 3; i ++)
       {
           if(max < sales[i][j])
           {
               max = sales[i][j];
               name = names[i];
           }
       }

       cout << "name is " << name << endl;

       cout << "Salesman " << name << " had the highest sale for the quarter " << j + 1 << " with $" << max << endl;    } }
```

Comment: Consider using line-by-line debug with "watches" window opened in you favorite IDE. It's really good in solving this kind of problems

Answer (score 0):

First some things, i assume that you are a beginner in c++ so i will give you some advice if you dont mind, avoid to use `using namespace std` try not to get used, here there is a explanation about [why you should not use it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice),and this is just because i am a bit obsessive but try to format your code better it will make easier to understand every part.

**Now the important part**, your code works perfectly but "sales name 1" does not print because once you set max here : `max = sales[0][j];` in case that this position is actually the max it will never enter in this if :

```
if(max < sales[i][j])
{
     max = sales[i][j];
     name = names[i];
}
```

So if it never enters in that if name will never be changed and thats why it does not print sales name 1 , so the solution is as simple as this changes where you set the `max = sales[0][j]` for this :

```
max = sales[0][j];
name = names[0];
```

Adding this last line will fix your problem.

Sorry if i didnt explain myself enough clearly (its my first answer :P)